# Unable to extends the base templates Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I had created a base.html with the following content.
**yarnMMS/templates/my/base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>Yarn Management System</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-page">

        <!-- Start content -->

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock  %}
        <!-- END content -->

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i am trying to extends my base.html .
**yarnMMS/templates/my/content.html**

```
{% extends 'my/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Content Block</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

But i am not getting required result. So please point out the mistake.

Here is my settings.py where i have added templates directory.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Where is the `base.html` located? Is it inside an app's template folder?

Comment: yes its inside the app folder templates.

Comment: Can you update your question with the directory structure of the app?

Comment: updated. Please check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extending and inheriting templates inside an app, you need to provide it's name to the tag.

This should work:

```
{% extends 'app_name/base.html' %}
```

If it's inside another folder in your project's `templates` directory, just provide the folder name:

```
{% extends 'folder_name/base.html' %}
```

Comment: its in project directory .Not in App directory.

Comment: @HassanALi Yes, just provide the name of the containing folder.

Comment: {% extends 'templates/my/base.html' %} like this

Comment: @HassanALi `{% extends 'my/base.html' %}`.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't Worked out.

Comment: @HassanALi That's strange. In your `TEMPLATES` settings, there's a list called `DIRS`. Is it empty, or does it contain the name of your project's `templates` folder?

Comment: 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

Comment: Do i have to install some module for template inheritance ?

Comment: @HassanALi No there's not extra module required for this. But I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: i am also amazed . Thanks for your time

Comment: @HassanALi Can you try moving the `base.html` out of the `my` folder and see if that works.

Comment: still same result . Nothing changed. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can add a section in the `settings.py` where its marked `TEMPLATES` to your question. But do check the following, it might be where the problem is.

Make sure in your `settings.py` module the following line exists, in the `TEMPLATES` setting:

```
...
TEMPLATES = [
             ...
             'DIRS': [
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
             ],
             ...
]
...
```

This tells django to look for templates in that directory, in this case `templates` directory in the project's base directory `BASE_DIR`, you can add as many as you like, just make sure to add them to the `DIRS` setting and specify the location on the disk and then call them in your templates!